# Why are my output multiplies when I press the button? I want it to have single output every click

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
const btn = document.querySelector('button')
let x = 0

const load = ()=>{
    btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        console.log(x++)
        load()
    })
}
load()
```

first click : 0
second click : 1, 2
third click: 3, 4, 5, 6
fourth click : 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14

Please help how to make my output into this:
first click : 0
second click : 1
third click : 2
fourth click: 3

Comment: Cause you add one more listener each time when you call `load`

Comment: `load` registers an event handler, which calls `load`, which registers an event handler, which calls `load`, which registers ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`load` registers an event handler. If the event handler calls `load` again it will add yet another event handler, etc.

Just don't call `load` inside the event handler. There isn't even a reason to define `load` at all:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
let x = 0;

btn.addEventListener('click',() => {
  console.log(x++)
});
```

Comment: but I want it that way, is there no way I can make it work aside from your code?

Comment: You can have keep the `load` function if you want to. Just don't call it again inside the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your event listener, you are invoking the load function, which registers the listener again.  First time, you have 1 listener.  When you press the button, your listener increases x and logs it, and invokes load which registers the listener for a second time. Next time you press the button, ...

Comment: Thank you but why does it happens? is there any way I can make it work?

Comment: Don't invoke the load function within the listener (i.e., remove `load()` after the `console.log(...)` statement).